# PowerShell Process Mitigations Not working

Tags: firefox, powershell

I have a script that enables the following process mitigations for firefox via powershell:

```
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable sehop
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable enableropsimexec
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable enableropcallercheck
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable enableropstackpivot
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable enableimportaddressfilter
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable BlockLowLabelImageLoads
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable PreferSystem32
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable BlockRemoteImageLoads
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable DisableNonSystemFonts
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable EnforceModuleDependencySigning
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable StrictCFG
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable SuppressExports
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable CFG
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable AllowThreadsToOptOut
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable DisableExtensionPoints
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable StrictHandle
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable HighEntropy
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable BottomUp
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable RequireInfo
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable ForceRelocateImages
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable EmulateAtlThunks
Set-ProcessMitigation -name firefox.exe -enable DEP
```

However, when i do `get-processmitigation firefox.exe`, I get the following output:

```
ProcessName                      : firefox.exe
Source                           : Registry
Id                               : 0

DEP:
    Enable                             : ON
    EmulateAtlThunks                   : ON
    Override DEP                       : False

ASLR:
    BottomUp                           : ON
    Override BottomUp                  : False
    ForceRelocateImages                : ON
    RequireInfo                        : ON
    Override ForceRelocate             : False
    HighEntropy                        : ON
    Override High Entropy              : False

StrictHandle:
    Enable                             : NOTSET
    Override StrictHandle              : False

System Call:
    DisableWin32kSystemCalls           : NOTSET
    Audit                              : NOTSET
    Override SystemCall                : False

ExtensionPoint:
    DisableExtensionPoints             : ON
    Override ExtensionPoint            : False

DynamicCode:
    BlockDynamicCode                   : NOTSET
    AllowThreadsToOptOut               : NOTSET
    Audit                              : NOTSET
    Override DynamicCode               : False

CFG:
    Enable                             : NOTSET
    SuppressExports                    : OFF
    Override CFG                       : False
    StrictControlFlowGuard             : NOTSET
    Override StrictCFG                 : False

BinarySignature:
    MicrosoftSignedOnly                : NOTSET
    AllowStoreSignedBinaries           : OFF
    EnforceModuleDependencySigning     : ON
    AuditMicrosoftSignedOnly           : NOTSET
    AuditStoreSigned                   : OFF
    AuditEnforceModuleDependencySigning: NOTSET
    Override MicrosoftSignedOnly       : False
    Override DependencySigning         : False

FontDisable:
    DisableNonSystemFonts              : ON
    Audit                              : NOTSET
    Override FontDisable               : False

ImageLoad:
    BlockRemoteImageLoads              : ON
    AuditRemoteImageLoads              : NOTSET
    Override BlockRemoteImages         : False
    BlockLowLabelImageLoads            : ON
    AuditLowLabelImageLoads            : NOTSET
    Override BlockLowLabel             : False
    PreferSystem32                     : ON
    AuditPreferSystem32                : NOTSET
    Override PreferSystem32            : False

Payload:
    EnableExportAddressFilter          : NOTSET
    AuditEnableExportAddressFilter     : NOTSET
    Override ExportAddressFilter       : False
    EnableExportAddressFilterPlus      : NOTSET
    AuditEnableExportAddressFilterPlus : NOTSET
    Override ExportAddressFilterPlus   : False
    EAFModules                         : {}
    EnableImportAddressFilter          : ON
    AuditEnableImportAddressFilter     : NOTSET
    Override ImportAddressFilter       : False
    EnableRopStackPivot                : ON
    AuditEnableRopStackPivot           : NOTSET
    Override EnableRopStackPivot       : False
    EnableRopCallerCheck               : ON
    AuditEnableRopCallerCheck          : NOTSET
    Override EnableRopCallerCheck      : False
    EnableRopSimExec                   : ON
    AuditEnableRopSimExec              : NOTSET
    Override EnableRopSimExec          : False

SEHOP:
    Enable                             : NOTSET
    TelemetryOnly                      : OFF
    Audit                              : NOTSET
    Override SEHOP                     : False

Heap:
    TerminateOnError                   : NOTSET
    Override HEAP                      : False

Child Process:
    DisallowChildProcessCreation       : NOTSET
    Audit                              : NOTSET
    Override ChildProcess              : False
```

As you can see, many of the process mitigations which are not on by default are indeed not set. However, when I enter one specific one, such as the process mitigation for sehop, it does show that it is enabled. Any time I try to enable all of them( even one command at a time ), or run all of them in a script, they don't get enabled and there is some sort of error.

Why is powershell refusing to enable these process mitigations? Why is Windows refusing to accept my request?

Comment: Do you get some warnings like `WARNING: Error while setting SEHOP: C0000022`? Run your script elevated…